# C# Convert mongodb bson to json with NumberLong

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net, bson

I have a dynamic mongoDB bson document that I try to desirialized to c# Dictionary object.
The bson document contains LongNumber type and I have troubles with it.

```
var json = entity.BsonValue.ToJson();
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

> { "displayMode" : "readings", "yellow" : { "from" : NumberLong("500000000000000"), "to" : NumberLong("500000000000000") }, "red" : { "from" : NumberLong("500000000000000"), "to" : NumberLong("500000000000000") }}

This is the code I try to run and bson that I try to convert example.
Looks like I cant handle the NumberLong("") since json beehive differently
The bson field is dynamic and can contain anything, that is why its dictionary of object.
Is there any way to make this deserialize maybe add jsonWriterSettings and how to?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I found out that simple `new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict })`
will do the job for the long numbers.

Comment: For more clarification, the new code would look like this

`var json = entity.BsonValue.ToJson(new MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonOutputMode.Strict });
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
`

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = entity.BsonValue.ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.RelaxedExtendedJson });
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

Relaxed Mode: Relaxed representation that loses type information for BSON numeric types and uses a more human-readable representation of BSON dates. See the Extended JSON specification for a description of this mode.