# MongoDB c# Deserialization - property not recognized

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I'm upgrading from using BsonDocument everywhere, to using deserialization on POCO objects.

Overall the objects are populated with correct values, but i'm having a problem with the code below, values on the EventReferenceEntry.Id property - which are always 0.

Perhaps worth knowing, is that if i remove "BsonIgnoreExtraElements" attribute from the EventReferenceEntry class, i get an error "Element 'i' does not match any field or property of class  "

I've also tried setting EventReferenceEntry.Id to Int64 and UInt64, but no difference.

The driver is version 2.7.3, i tried it with a fresh installation of the latest version, but it's the same problem.

The database is a series of events. An event has:
_id = Int64
_t = Int32 (the type of the event)
_r = an array of objects (references to other objects, entities or events, that are relevant.)

C# Code of the POCO objects

```
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class EventEntry
    {
        [BsonElement("_id")]
        public ulong Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("_t")]
        public int Type { get; set; }

        public DateTime Time { get { return new DateTime((long)Id, DateTimeKind.Utc); } }

        [BsonElement("_r")]
        public List<EventReferenceEntry> References { get; set; }

    }

    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class EventReferenceEntry
    {
        [BsonElement("i")]
        public UInt64 Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("n")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("a")]
        public int Asset { get; set; }

        public EventReferenceEntry()
        {
        }
    }
```

An example database entry

```
{
"_id" : NumberLong(637684658186492532),
"_t" : 1058,
"_r" : [ 
    {
        "n" : "p",
        "i" : NumberLong(637662370697662760)
    }, 
    {
        "n" : "a",
        "a" : 1202
    }, 
    {
        "n" : "o",
        "i" : NumberLong(637684655676255124),
        "a" : 2934
    }
]
}
```

Comment: try use `ulong` instead `UInt64`, or even just `long`, I'm not sure that long on the db side is considered the same with `ulong` on the driver side

Comment: Doesnt seem to change anything, i just tried ulong, long, UInt64, Int64. But worth noting is that the EventEntry.Id, which is the practically the same thing, works ok with all 4 of those types. I will load the MongoDB driver with source code, so I can poke around what goes on internally.

Comment: not sure, I would suggest taking one document from database and playing with him in simple console application with changing property types in POCO/db or element names in POCO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Convert mongodb bson to json with NumberLong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631026/c-sharp-convert-mongodb-bson-to-json-with-numberlong)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631026/c-sharp-convert-mongodb-bson-to-json-with-numberlong is about converting bson-to-json in a way that produces valid JSON. My issue is with applying BSON to a DotNet object - which mostly works, just that one property in a nested object gets ignored.

Comment: note: don't use `_t` as an element name since this key is used in discriminator https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/polymorphism/ logic in the driver, not sure whether it's caused issues, but at the very least it looks wrong

Comment: I use the _t as "type id" with int32 type, then I have an internal dictionary that looks up what type that is. Not using the proper kind of binding to classes yet though. But thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and solution.

A property in the class (in my case EventReferenceEntry) cannot be named “Id” or “id”, I guess that a property named that is assumed to be bound to the _id bson property. It can however be named “ID” or “Ident” or anything else, and the value gets assigned.